# if there are multiple dates for an ID then only min and max date should be present as shown

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have data in dataframe in this following format:

```
Row_1 AB123, 01-mar-2011, 30-mar-2011, data1, data2 
Row_2 CD123, **01-mar-2011**, 30-mar-2011, data1, data2 
Row_3 CD123, 01-apr-2011, **30-apr-2011**, data1, data2 
Row_4 EF123, 01-nov-2011, 30-nov-2011, data1, data2
```

Need the final row to be:

```
Row_1 AB123, 01-mar-2011,30-mar-2011,data1,data2 
Row_2 CD123, **01-mar-2011**,**30-apr-2011**,data1,data2
Row_3 EF123, 01-nov-2011, 30-nov-2011,data1,data2
```

Comment: explain what do you need? how do you get a second dataframe? why is `Row_3` deleting?

Comment: Sorry row 3 isn't deleting. Have edited it. Need a new data frame as seen in the second table

Comment: you don't answer my questions? with formula you want get second dataframe

Comment: need the min date and max date for a particular id. If you see for id 'CD123' there are 4 dates altogether. but need only min and max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["col2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col2"])
df["col3"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col3"])

df_out = df.groupby("col1", as_index=False).agg(
    {
        "col2": "min",
        "col3": "max",
        "col4": "first",
        "col5": "first",
    }
)
```

Prints:

```
    col1       col2       col3   col4   col5
0  AB123 2011-03-01 2011-03-30  data1  data2
1  CD123 2011-03-01 2011-04-30  data1  data2
2  EF123 2011-11-01 2011-11-30  data1  data2
```

---

`df` used:

```
    col1         col2         col3   col4   col5
0  AB123  01-mar-2011  30-mar-2011  data1  data2
1  CD123  01-mar-2011  30-mar-2011  data1  data2
2  CD123  01-apr-2011  30-apr-2011  data1  data2
3  EF123  01-nov-2011  30-nov-2011  data1  data2
```

Comment: Wow Thank you sooo much :D